# When is execle needed instead of execl?

Tags: c, environment-variables, exec

Consider this simple C program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        execl("script.sh", "script.sh", NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXIT_SUCCESS)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

with `script.sh` being

```
#!/bin/bash

case $DEBUG in
true)
    echo "Debug mode on"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Debug mode off"
    ;;
esac
```

If I compile the C program with `gcc -o foo main.c` and call it with

`DEBUG=true ./foo`

then the output is `Debug mode on`, so the script actually got the environment variables I passed to the program `foo`, even though I didn't use `execle`. In which scenario then is it necessary to use `execle` (other than wanting than wanting to specify the environment variables directly in the source code)? I'm talking about people doing something like

```
extern char **environ;
...
execle(path, path, NULL, environ)
```

What's the purpose of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you don't want the environment to get inherited (you want the executable to start with an empty environment or an environment you've specifically set up for it).

Comment: So instead of the example at the bottom you could just use `execl`? I'm specifically talking about [this code](https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm/blob/59a9785786b3168dd2d979a0b87fa2faf4fefea1/src/settings.c#L33).

Comment: Yes. Passing `environ` as the environment argument to `execle` is equivalent to calling `execl`.